# Vielen Dank allen oder euch allen?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, english-to-german, difference, meaning-in-context

From what I understood *Vielen Dank* is the somewhat more formal version of thank you. I've seen *Vielen Dank euch allen* a couple of times before, but I don't understand what the *euch* is adding, instead of just saying *Vielen Dank allen* to say thank you everybody for exemple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

> Vielen Dank euch allen.

*euch* is the dative form of the personal pronoun 2nd person plural. The expression means "Thanks a lot to you all".

Your suggestion

> Vielen Dank allen.

is not idiomatic in German.

Comment: However you could say _Ich danke allen_, which uses the verb _danken_.

Comment: I'd also add *Vielen Dank an alle.*

Comment: Is "Vielen Dank allen" even grammatical?

Comment: @Spencer: Where do you draw the line between "ungrammatical" and "unidiomatic"?

Comment: In case it's not obvious, you'd only use *euch* if it's people you're on *du* terms with, otherwise *Ihnen*.

Comment: But it is for instance correct to say "Vielen Dank allen, die mir geholfen haben."

Answer (score 0):

First off: "Vielen Dank allen." is indeed correct.

It is an ellipse of an old construct:

> Dank sei + *Dativ*

For instance *Dank sei dem Herrn ...*.

@Spencer, @Sonyfreak:

> Vielen Dank allen, die geholfen haben.

Is indeed correct. "Dank" is not a verb here but - see above - a noun and the complete (today not used any more) phrase would be:

> Vielen Dank *sei* allen, ...